# ValueError: Input 0 of layer block1_conv1 is incompatible with the layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm new to DL and i'm trying to do an emotion recognition task with a VGG16 pre-trained network using FER2013 dateset, but when I try to predict results i get this error:

"ValueError: Input 0 of layer block1_conv1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape (None, 48, 48, 1)"

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sn
import skimage.io
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Dropout,BatchNormalization ,Activation
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.applications.nasnet import NASNetLarge
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive")

from zipfile import ZipFile
!unzip -q "/content/drive/MyDrive/archive.zip"

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   validation_split = 0.2,
                                  
        rotation_range=5,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        #zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')

valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                  validation_split = 0.2)

test_datagen  = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255
                                  )

train_dir='train'
train_dataset  = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                   target_size = (48,48),
                                                   class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                   subset = 'training',
                                                   batch_size = 64)

valid_dataset = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                  target_size = (48,48),
                                                  class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                  subset = 'validation',
                                                  batch_size = 64)

test_dir='test'
test_dataset = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir,
                                                  target_size = (48,48),
                                                  class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                  batch_size = 64)

base_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(input_shape=(48,48,3),include_top=False,weights="imagenet")

# Freezing Layers

for layer in base_model.layers[:-4]:
    layer.trainable=False
# Building Model

model=Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(32,kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(32,kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(32,kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(7,activation='softmax'))
# Model Summary

model.summary()

from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from IPython.display import Image
plot_model(model, to_file='convnet.png', show_shapes=True,show_layer_names=True)
Image(filename='convnet.png') 

def f1_score(y_true, y_pred): #taken from old keras source code
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    f1_val = 2*(precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon())
    return f1_val
METRICS = [
      tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
      tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
      tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),  
      tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
        f1_score,
]
lrd = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor = 'val_loss',patience = 20,verbose = 1,factor = 0.50, min_lr = 1e-10)

mcp = ModelCheckpoint('model.h5')

es = EarlyStopping(verbose=1, patience=20)

model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=METRICS)
history=model.fit(train_dataset,validation_data=valid_dataset,epochs = 5,verbose = 1,callbacks=[lrd,mcp,es])

model.save('vgg-16.h5')

import keras

model = keras.models.load_model('vgg-16.h5', compile = False)

METRICS = [
      tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
      tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
      tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),  
      tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
        f1_score,
]

model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=METRICS)

from keras.preprocessing import image

img = image.load_img("test/happy/PrivateTest_1140198.jpg",target_size = (48,48),color_mode = "grayscale")
img = np.array(img)
plt.imshow(img)
print(img.shape) #prints (48,48) that is the shape of our image

label_dict = {0:'Angry',1:'Disgust',2:'Fear',3:'Happy',4:'Neutral',5:'Sad',6:'Surprise'}
img = np.expand_dims(img,axis = 0) #makes image shape (1,48,48)
img = img.reshape(1,48,48,1)
result = model.predict(img)
```

Comment: Your `VGG16` model has 3 channels but you `img` is just 1.

Answer (score 1):

This pre-trained VGG16 network is set to receive input images of shape (48, 48, 3), the 3 channels corresponding to the RGB colors of the images.

At this line:

```
img = image.load_img("test/happy/PrivateTest_1140198.jpg",target_size = (48,48),color_mode = "grayscale")
```

You load an image with `color_mode="grayscale"`, which returns a 1 channel image.

To fit the expected input shape of your model, you need to set `color_mode="rgb"`, which yields a 3 channels RGB image.

Then, reshape your image to `img = img.reshape(1,48,48,3)` before passing it through the model.